# Installing pyodbc kaggle

Tags: python, pyodbc, kaggle

Going crazy here, just try to use pyodbc within kaggle. But getting error all the time

Internet is obviously switched on..

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHs9c.png)

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

sudo apt-get install python-pip

pip install pyodbc
```

if that will not work, try

```
yum install unixODBC-devel
```

If still it is not working, read documentation : [Installation of pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install)

Comment: Thanks but kaggle can not find these commands.

Also, the documention for insalling pyodbc doesn't touch the topic 'kaggle'

Answer (score 0):

```
!sudo apt install --yes python3-pip python3-dev  unixodbc-dev 
!pip install pyodbc
```

It shows very long extraction, its up to you to make it better.

Ref:
1st. The documentation linked in Thyrus' answer.
2nd. how to say yes in kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/146938

Comment: Please use three backticks (`\`\`\``) for code block highlighting as `>` means quote.